# changing String array to integers

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a method to take a String array and copies the elements into an Integer array then calculates an average. Not sure if im on the right path or if this is completely wrong.

```
 public static double CalculateAvg(String [] Grades)
   {
    int []Exams = new int[Grades.length];
    double AVG =0;
    int sum = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= Grades.length; i++)
    {
        Exams[i] = Integer.parseInt(Grades[i]);
        Exams[i] = j;
        sum +=j;
        AVG= (double)sum/4;
    }
    //return AVG;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `int j` variable ?

Comment: Why divide by 4?

Answer (score 5):

You have a lot of redundant variables. Try:

```
public static double CalculateAvg(String [] Grades) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Grades.length; i++) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(Grades[i]);
    }
    return sum/Grades.length;
}
```

By the way it can be done by stream api. Just for your educational purposes:

```
double avg = Arrays.stream(Grades)
      .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
      .average().orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

to calculate the avg you need to divide by the number of elements
i think this what you are looking for

```
           public static double CalculateAvg(String [] Grades)
           {
              int []Exams = new int[Grades.length];
              double AVG =0;
              int sum = 0;
              int j = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i <= Grades.length; i++)
               {
                 Exams[i] = Integer.parseInt(Grades[i]);

                 AVG= (double) Exams[i]/Grades.length;
                 }
            return AVG;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Java 8 Streams and Lambda expressions like illustrated below:

```
    public static double calculateAverage(String[] grades)
    {
    return Arrays.stream(grades)
                 .map(grade->Double.parseDouble(grade))
                 .reduce(0.0,(sum, grade) -> sum + grade)/grades.length;
    }
```